# encryption of ebs volume after creation amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ebs, amazon-kms

I want to use KMS to encrypt my volumes. I know how to do it upon creation but with the already created volumes I cant seem to find a solution. 
Is the RDS logic applied for ebs too? Is there only the possibility to do it upon creation?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/778759/how-to-convert-a-unencrypted-ebs-to-be-encrypted

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a snapshot, then copy the snapshot with the "encrypt" option enabled during the copy process, then create a new volume from the encrypted snapshot.

Comment: the problem is that upon creation of the snapshot encryption option is not editable and it is set to no. and later when I am creating a new volume from the snapshot, again the option is not editable when I choose my snapshot.

Comment: Perhaps you should open a ticket with AWS about that.